# How to get a list box to display its results based on previous combo box.

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to populate a combo box from SQL where when I select an Item from the first box the options get limited in the 2nd box. The fist box has a selected index change event, but I can't seem to figure out how to limit the results.

Here is what I have:

```
private void cb_college_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lb_allMajors.Items.Clear();
        lb_allMajors.Items.Add(cb_college.SelectedIndex); 
    }


private void populateMajors()
    {
        try
        {
            string SQL;
            SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT major_name FROM majors";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lb_allMajors.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }
```

Each major in the majors table in the database has a college ID column that links to the colleges table.  So when you select a college (e.g. Business) I want the major box to only show majors in the college of business.

Comment: search **winforms cascading combobox**, and a lot of result such as [c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/cascading-combobox-in-windows-application-using-C-Sharp/)

Comment: where are you having problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on exactly what you're after or what the example is showing, but I think you just need to supply your `populateMajors()` method with a parameter containing the college ID, or the SelectedIndex, whichever you want to use.

For example:

```
private void cb_college_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populateMajors(cb_college.SelectedIndex); // OR More likely Get College ID from Combobox 
}

private void populateMajors(int CollegeId)
{
    try
    {
        string SQL;
        SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT major_name FROM majors WHERE <yourcollegeindexcol> = " + CollegeId;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lb_allMajors.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
}
```

I doubt that SelectedIndex is the right parameter to send, but you get the picture.

You might find it better to use the ComboBox.DataSource property too rather than Items.Add - search for ComboBox.DataSource online to see it's usage.

Comment: I think you are right about the getting the college id form the combobox.  But I need to make sure the combobox contains that ID

Comment: That's where ComboBox.DataSource comes in - an example: You can get your college data from the SQL DB and store in a DataTable with columns of CollegeId and CollegeName. You then set your cb_college.DisplayMember to be "CollegeName", and cb_college.ValueMember to be "CollegeId". Then, cb_college.SelectedValue contains the CollegeId, but it is the names displayed in the list.